# Need to step down votage to test a heart rate monitor

Tags: ttl

I'd like to create a test bed for heart rate monitor devices. The type of monitors I'd like to test use chest straps to detect the voltage fluctuations caused by the heart.  I'm told this votage fluctuation is on the order of 1 milli volt.

Basically, I need a circuit that can be attached to the device to simulate a heart beat so I can test various heart rate monitors without the need for a human wearing the strap.

Ideally, I'd need a circuit that can create pulses from ~.5Hz—6Hz.  The voltage of these pulses needs to be on the order of ~1mV.

I can create such a circuit with say a 555 timer, but the part I'm unsure about is how to step the voltage down from TTL voltage to mV.  Perhaps a bleeder resistor?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why? Which specs are you planning to test besides BPM? CMRR? SNR? Noise rejection? Sensitivity?

Comment: I want to reverse engineer an old HRM watch that I like so I can re-implement it in software.  All I want to do is to cause the HRM strap to detect a heart rate of my choice (without having to wear it).

Comment: The issue is that building something that also detects your fake signal does not mean you've built a heart rate monitor

Comment: I'm not trying to build a heart rate monitor.  I'm trying to reverse engineer an existing heart rate monitor.

Comment: The sinus pulse also has 30 Hz ringing can trigger false readings but like arythmea. Do you know how to extract this pulse and ignore the ringing in S/W or H/W ?

Comment: The frequency counter in BPM is the easy part. The harder part is the front end A/D that is error free.

Comment: It seems like the asker is going to write new software for existing hardware, so some parts of the puzzle are removed.  But it remains true that detecting a fake signal that satisfied the original software **does not** mean that the askers new software will usefully recover *actual* heart signals.  The question posted is about step 1, faking the signal to satisfy the existing algorithm, but the real problem is that's likely not as useful as imagined.  Simulating a human heart in order to develop a good re-implementation algorithm is quite a bit more complicated!

Comment: Just to clear it up, all I'm trying to do is to cause an old heart rate monitor watch to perceive an electrical signal as a certain heart rate.  This instrument is pretty simple, it's not an EKG, it only cares about 'beats' and internally totally ignores the shape of the pulse. If I can get a circuit that allows me to dial the desired heart rate up or down within human parameters, then this will enable me to reverse engineer some algorithms implemented by the watch (namely the so called workload index)

Answer (score 0):

A balloon that the device under test can be secured to or held against.

The balloon can be pulsed at a frequency of choice using perhaps a linear actuator or motor to hit the balloon with a “hammer” or something similar.

Comment: It's not movement that triggers the heart rate monitor, it's electrical signals from the heart.  Surprisingly these are strong enough to be measured at the surface of the skin.

Comment: It depends how much effort you want to make at duplicating the signal.  Cheap and dirty pulse with 3V battery and small coupling cap and 10M pot  or sinus signal.  See below. Use a small relay coil for L.

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/yazhsgzl

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 That looks awesome.  Stupid question: What's generating the signal?  Is it external or is the circuit generating the pulse itself?

Comment: 1st stage astable osc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109969/discussion-between-pnadeau-and-tony-stewart-sunnyskyguy-ee75).